# Jenkins declarative pipeline conditional post action

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins declarative pipeline and want to perform some post build actions depending on the build status.

To be more precise, I want to send an email when the build status changed (from success to failure, or success to unstable, or failure to success).

Here is my pipeline:

```java
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('test') {
            agent any
            steps {                
                sh './tests.sh'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        changed {
            // Send different emails depending on build status
            // Success       -> anything else
            // Anything else -> Success
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: So what's your actual problem? Sending the email?

Comment: Sorry I realize that I was not that clear... my problem is that I would like to send an email on every failures, but only one when the status moves to success. I'd like to recover the feature "receive mail on failed builds and on fixed builds".

Comment: In fact, my question was more generalist and about "how can I write conditions inside a post action block"

Comment: You mentioned `changed` in your question. Why don't you use that?

Comment: I wanted to have notifications on every status except success (i.e, I want a new email at each failure). But you are right, I finally used exactly the snippet I posted and live with this. I have another use case where I need to perform some post actions only on certain branches, but your other response with script blocks solves this problem too! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just to throw it out there, you can also make use of the `fixed` and `regression` blocks. `fixed` is called when your build goes green after either failure or unstable, but not after aborted. `regression` is called when your build result is worse than the previous build (success -> unstable -> failure -> aborted, worse result to the right). It sounds like using `changed` with the custom function is what you were looking for specifically, but adding this just in case someone lands here searching for something similar.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For writing conditions you can define your own methods.

For example, if you want to send an email only when the build status changes:

```
def notifyStatusChangeViaEmail(buildStatus) {
    def status

    switch (buildStatus) {
        case 'SUCCESS':
            status = 'is now green again!'
            break

        case 'UNSTABLE':
            status = 'has become unstable..'
            break

        case 'FAILURE':
            status = 'has turned RED :('
            break
    }

    emailext (
        subject: "Job '${env.JOB_NAME}' ${status}",
        body: "See ${env.BUILD_URL} for more details",
        recipientProviders: [
            [$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'], 
            [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']
        ]
    )
}

pipeline {
    ...

    post {
        changed {
            // Will trigger only when job status changes: GREEN -> RED, RED -> GREEN, etc
            notifyStatusChangeViaEmail(currentBuild.currentResult)
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, you would also want to put `notifyStatusChangeViaEmail` method definiton in your [shared pipeline library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) so that it could be re-used in other jobs/pipelines.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to this pipeline:

```
post {
        success {
            emailext ( 
                subject: '${DEFAULT_SUBJECT}'+'SUCESSFUL', 
                body: '${DEFAULT_CONTENT}',
                to: '${EMAIL_RECIPIENTS}'
                );
                slackSend (color: 'good', message: ":csp_operational: ${env.JOB_NAME} - #${env.BUILD_NUMBER} Success (<${env.BUILD_URL}|Open>)");


        }
        failure {
            emailext ( 
                subject: '${DEFAULT_SUBJECT}'+'FAILED!', 
                body: '${DEFAULT_CONTENT}',
                to: '${EMAIL_RECIPIENTS}'
                );
                slackSend (color: 'danger', message: ":x: ${env.JOB_NAME} - #${env.BUILD_NUMBER} Failure (<${env.BUILD_URL}|Open>)");


        }

    }
```

You can set the Default Email parameters using Extended Email Plugin, Jenkins-> Configure Jenkins -> Extended Email Configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, I would not like to receive a mail on each success but only on the first success following a non success build.

Answer (score 0):

Exemple : failure & unstable to success

```
if (currentBuild.result == 'SUCCESS') {  if(hudson.model.Result.FAILURE.equals(currentBuild.rawBuild.getPreviousBuild()?.getResult()) || hudson.model.Result.UNSTABLE.equals(currentBuild.rawBuild.getPreviousBuild()?.getResult())) {
SEND MAIL()
}
}
```

for send email : https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/15/declarative-notifications/

Comment: Thank you, that will do the trick, it looks complicated for what was a simple checkbox before, but it definitely solves my problem!

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to write conditionals inside a post action ? "when" statement looks interesting but is not allowed inside a post block :(

Comment: That's for scripted pipeline (use a `script` block in declarative).

Answer (score 0):

[@psalvi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45464910/265954) was imho on the right track, but @mikael-gibert wanted in his comment to get notifications only for the first fixed build. Jenkins declarative pipelines can do that, see https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post. Here an example:

```js
pipeline {
    // [...]
    post {
        always {
            script {
                // Examples of stuff you could do, based on some custom parameters and functions
                if (params.buildAndPublish && branchIsMain()) {
                    currentBuild.description = 'NOT promoted '
                }

                currentBuild.description = (currentBuild.description ?: '') + '[' + (params.customArtifactVersion ?: mavenArtifactVersion) + ']'

                if (params.buildAndPublish) {
                    // Tell Bitbucket about this build and its result
                    notifyBitbucket(credentialsId: config.credentialsId)

                    // Archive test results
                    junit(allowEmptyResults: true, testResults: "**/target/surefire-reports/**.xml,**/target/failsafe-reports/**.xml")
                }
            }
        }

        failure {
            emailext recipientProviders: [culprits(), requestor()],
                    subject: "[Jenkins] Build failed: ${env.JOB_NAME} #${env.BUILD_NUMBER}",
                    body: "Hello,\n\nBuild failed: ${env.JOB_NAME} / ${env.BRANCH_NAME} #${env.BUILD_NUMBER}.\nDetails: ${env.BUILD_URL}\n\nJenkins"
        }

        fixed {
            emailext recipientProviders: [culprits(), requestor()],
                    subject: "[Jenkins] Build fixed: ${env.JOB_NAME} #${env.BUILD_NUMBER}",
                    body: "Hello,\n\nBuild fixed: ${env.JOB_NAME} / ${env.BRANCH_NAME} #${env.BUILD_NUMBER}.\nDetails: ${env.BUILD_URL}\n\nJenkins"
        }
    }
}
```